# Separation of variables and integration constants

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am referring to [this page from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine-GordonEquation.html) concerning the *Sine-Gordon Equation*.

I have two questions:

**(1)** It is said that equation (20), which is
$$
\frac{(\phi_{xx}/\phi)_x}{\phi\phi_x}+\frac{(\psi_{tt}/\psi)_t}{\psi\psi_t}=0\tag{20},
$$
implies, by separation of variables,
$$
\frac{(\phi_{xx}/\phi)_x}{\phi\phi_x}=-\frac{(\psi_{tt}/\psi)_t}{\psi\psi_t}=-6k^2\tag{21}.
$$
How to see this? Of course, since we have that both terms are functions of the independent variables $x$ and $t$, respectively, the only way they can coincide is that both are some constant $\lambda$. This constant is chosen to be positive, $\lambda=k^2$, alright. But where does the factor $6$ come from?

**(2)** One thus gets
$$
\frac{\phi_{xx}}{\phi}=-3k^2\phi^2+C_1,\quad\frac{\psi_{tt}}{\psi}=3k^2\psi^2+C_2
$$
with integration constants $C_1$ and $C_1$. In the link, they call $C_1=m$. Then, they get $C_2=\sqrt{m^2-1}$, cf. equation (24).

How does one see that $C_2=\sqrt{C_1^2-1}$?

In the link they say that the constants are connected by equation "$(\Diamond)$", but there is no such equation. However, I think, that equation (16),
$$
v(x,t)=4\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(t)}\right]\tag{16},
$$
is meant. Nonetheless, this does not explain to me why the second constants of integration is $\sqrt{m^2-1}$.